# Output swatches in SassDoc from a Color Map

Tags: sass, documentation

I'm trying to generate color swatches in my Sass documentation via [SassDoc](http://sassdoc.com/).

This works for a single color:

```
/// Orange
/// @type Color
$orange: #e13400;
```

Is there also a way to output swatches for color Maps in SassDoc?

```
/// Orange tints
/// @type Map
$orange: (
  lightest: #ffe5ca,
  lighter: #f5b180,
  light: #e77636,
  base: #e13400,
  dark: #711f03,
  darker: #581902,
  darkest: #391102,
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://github.com/SassDoc/sassdoc-theme-default/issues/28#issuecomment-76356923

It is possible if you repeat the Color values in @prop definitions.

```
/// Orange tints
/// @group Colors
/// @type Map
/// @prop {Color} lightest [#ffe5ca]
/// @prop {Color} lighter [#f5b180]
/// @prop {Color} light [#e77636]
/// @prop {Color} default [#e13400]
/// @prop {Color} dark [#711f03]
/// @prop {Color} darker [#581902]
/// @prop {Color} darkest [#391102]
$orange: (
  lightest: #ffe5ca,
  lighter: #f5b180,
  light: #e77636,
  default: #e13400,
  dark: #711f03,
  darker: #581902,
  darkest: #391102,
);
```

Comment: It would be helpful for future visitors if you provided an example.  Link only answers are frowned on.